# Define a fixed size ArrayList

Tags: kotlin

How can I initialize an array with a fixed size?
The following does not work properly because the variable indicators has a length of 0 but the count variable passed in has a value of 4.

```
    //count is 4
    private fun setuptIndicators(count:Int)
    {

     //indicators is 0
    val indicators = ArrayList<ImageView>(count)

 
     //Not running beacuse indicators is 0
     indicators.forEachIndexed { index, element ->


     }


    ...

    }
```

Comment: You must initialize the arraylist with items because now you tell it that it has 4 items but there is no imageView added so it can't loop to that item.

Comment: If you want it to always be 4 elements, then you should think of using Array instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your posted code is initializing an ArrayList with an initial capacity:

```
val indicators = ArrayList<ImageView>(count)
```

This list is initially empty.

If you want it to have a fixed size, you need to supply initial values for each element. Kotlin provides a convenience function for that: the function [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list.html) creates a list with the given size and uses the supplied lambda to create each element. In your case, you would write it like this:

```
private fun setuptIndicators(count:Int) {
    val indicators = MutableList<ImageView>(count) { index ->
        createElement(index)
    }
    ...
}
```

where `createElement` returns an ImageView instance for the given `index`, and becomes the value of the element at that index of the ArrayList.